# URL Scheme for Google Gmail?

Tags: 8.1-oreo, hyperlinks, url

WhatsApp and many other services offer *URL Schemes* (they work like direct links or deep links) for their apps. An example is **whatsapp://**.
Is there one available for Google Gmail? 
I tried these and they are not working for the latest Gmail release on Android 8.1:

```
googlegmail:///co?subject=<subject text>&body=<body text>
googlegmail://
gmail://
```

Comment: The AndroidManifest.xml of GMail indicates that it registers the following URL schemes: `auth` `mailto` `gmail2from` `content` `package` and `android_secret_code`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL schema does not necessarily begin with a unique protocol. For example, if you click this link https://www.youtube.com/ with the YouTube app installed, you'll be prompted to open it in the app.

AFAIK the Gmail app doesn't have a "supported links" defined, so you have no chance to make a link open in Gmail.

Comment: If you try to login to https://gmail.com in the Chrome Browser on Android, there will be a dialog with a button named "Open in the app" on the first visit. If you click it the Gmail app (if installed)  will be launched. I couldn't find out how they did it but my guess is an URL Scheme.

Comment: @Tom That could be the web gmail.com detecting your browser and prompting you, not the Android system.

Comment: Yes exactly. So it should be possible to launch the Android Gmail app from the browser, right?

Comment: @Tom No, not exactly. It depends on gmail.com 's web page instead of the Gmail app or the Android system. That means you're not able to make an arbitrary Gmail link open in the app, but only a selected set of them.